# Click in two buttons automatically

Tags: javascript, android, html, button, youtube

im having problems with the Youtube iframe videos on my website for mobile phones.
Youtube doesnt allow autoplay videos so the user in the website need to click the song, then click on pause and then click play to start the song, and i want to know if is posible to add some code to automate this, so when the user click in the song the pause button get clicked and the song pause and then automatically click again on play button to start the song, here is my code:
http://prntscr.com/an95lx

```
<div class="buttons">
    <i class="icon icon-to-start prev"></i>
    <i class="icon icon-play toggle-play" ng-if="!player.loadingTrack && !player.isPlaying"></i>
    <i class="icon icon-pause toggle-play" ng-if="!player.loadingTrack && player.isPlaying"></i>
    <i class="icon icon-spin2 track-loading spin" ng-if="player.loadingTrack"></i>
    <i class="icon icon-to-end next"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `object.invokeMember()` function.

For YT, the code looks like this:

```
var yourIframe = document.getElementById('player'); //or whatever your player ID is
yourIframe.document.getElementsByName('ytp-play-button')[0].invokeMember('onClick');
```